# glGetnUniformfv crashes for no reason?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I tried getting an `uniform vec3` from the fragment shader to my CPU using `glGetnUniformfv`. According to the documentation this should perfectly work. It also works when only getting a `float` from the shader. But when used like this,

```
float f[3] = {0.0f};
glGetnUniformfv(program, glGetUniformLocation(program, name.c_str()), 3, f);
```

my program crashes. I checked the `glGetUniformLocation` but it had a valid output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're using a context that actually supports OpenGL 4.5+, get the vec3 using "the old way" like this:

```
float f[3] = {0.0f};
glGetUniformfv(program, glGetUniformLocation(program, name.c_str()), f);
```

The new desktop-only glGet**n**Uniform entry points exist only for extra safety, similar to strncpy vs strcpy.

Also, if you *do* use the glGet**n** variant, you should pass 12 instead of 3 for *bufSize* since it's a byte count.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation

Answer (score 3):

The third parameter to the `glGetnUniform` family of functions is not actually the number of entries in the array. It is the byte size of the array pointed to by `f`. Which, because `f` is an array rather than just a pointer to an array, would be `sizeof(f)`.

Now, your implementation shouldn't have crashed, so there's probably something else going on there. But this is the problem in the code you've provided.

Comment: Where does the spec say `glGetnUniform`'s `bufSize` is in bytes?  Wasn't seeing language to that effect in the main `glGetnUniform*()` area on page 164 in the GL 4.5 spec or in the general discussion of command-structure & types in section 2.2 starting on page 10.

Comment: Regardless if it is stated in the documentation, neither way is working!

Comment: Note that GetnUniform was added in GL 4.5 and does not exist in 4.4, so your context needs to support 4.5.It is likely that you can simply use `glGetUniformfv` (without the `n`).

Comment: @prideout This seems to be it, is there any way to get a `vec3` without such new OpenGL versions?

Comment: @user11914177: There's what prideout said.

Comment: @genpfault: "*Wasn't seeing language to that effect in the main glGetnUniform*() area on page 164 in the GL 4.5 spec or in the general discussion of command-structure & types in section 2.2 starting on page 10.*" It's right there: "An `INVALID_OPERATION` error is generated by `GetnUniform*` if the **buffer size** required to store the requested data is greater than `bufSize`." Emphasis added. It's not an item count. Indeed, there's a [fixed bug report on functions that use `bufSize` as a parameter name that should be using a different name.(https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenGL-API/issues/52)